# using jquery Validation

Tags: jquery, css, validation

I'm using  [jquery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). I am trying to control where the error message will appear.

How can i do that?

10x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `errorPlacement` method:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent("td").next("td"));
    }
});
```

Comment: this isn't in a table format . can i do that in a div with an id?

Comment: Of course you can. I just posted a sample which you could adapt to your scenario. You can append the error wherever you like.